# How to make a forEach loop wait for each Ajax function to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have an `array` of statements and I want to loop through each and submit to the `server` via an `ajax` call. I have to make sure each `ajax` request is executed before the next request is sent, because on the `server` side code, I am creating a `unique key` for this `array` of statements. What happens is before I can commit the first request, the second request comes in and I end up have 2 separate keys being created since it sees each of them as a first time request. I can't rely on timeout entirely and the code I have so far, continues with the loop.

```
function formPostSubmission(form){
    var parts = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var i = 0;
    parts.forEach(function(entry) {
        i++;
        datafield ={
            answer:entry,
            displayOrder:i,
            ajaxName:'statementPartialSubmit'
        };
        $.when(submitAjaxData(form, datafield)).then(function succesHandler(data){
            console.log("promise test "+data);
            console.log("Below request ");
        },
        function errorHandler(){
            console.log("Error occurred ");
        })
        console.log("Go for next ");
    });
}

function  submitAjaxData(form, datafield) {
    console.log(" called submitAjaxData  ");
    var loadurl = domainName + "/ajax-call-handler";
    return $.ajax({
        url: loadurl,
        method: "GET",
        data: datafield
    });
}
```

I was hoping to check response data for a success and then proceed within the loop. But this is how my `console` prints.

```
called submitAjaxData
Go for next
called submitAjaxData 
Go for next
promise test  
Below request
promise test 
Below request
```

Answer (score 3):

use promises :

```
 var promises = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < $total_files; i++) {
 // jQuery returns a prom 
   promises.push($.ajax({
  /* your ajax config*/
  }))
 }

Promise.all(promises)
.then(responseList => {
 console.dir(responseList)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Sari. I just tried this. Can you explain how this is supposed to work. I see that the loop gets the first element and then prints the console message right after the ajax call. But I added a time param to the ajax request and I see the same time added for both the request.

Comment: This does not guarantee that the requests are sent sequentially!

Comment: Yes, I did some more tests and it isn't sent sequentially.

Comment: `Promise.all` just returns all resolved promises at once, or fails if one promise gets rejected. As @Fitzi said, it does not guarantee that they will be solved sequentially

Comment: I post another solution

Comment: @SariMasri when you're pushing `$.ajax` you're also triggering it, best you can do is wrap it under a function and call it later, now the problem moves to `Promise.all` because it doesn't call functions. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this solution by using `await` , for example :

```
for (let f of files) {
    await $.ajax({/* your ajax config*/ });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function, **PromiseAllSeq**, to execute an array of promises sequentially.

You can pass a callback as the second parameter if you choose, but given your issue i've put together a working **demo** based on your code.

```js
console.clear();
/**
 *  Promises will wait for each other and will return any[].
 *  If a promise is rejected it will stop.
 *  @param arr - (Promise<any> | ()=>Promise<any>)[] - Accepts promise or a function that returns a promise
 *  @param callback(response, index) - If callback 'returns' it will overwrite the current response. Useful for changing the response.
 *  @returns any[]
 */
const PromiseAllSeq = (arr, callback) => {

  let result = [];

  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    callback = () => {};
  }

  const rec = (arr) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (arr.length) {

        (typeof arr[0] === 'function' ? arr[0]() : arr[0]).then(res => {

          let cb = callback(res, result.length);

          result = result.concat(typeof cb !== 'undefined' ? cb : res);

          arr.splice(0, 1);

          resolve(arr.length ? rec(arr) : result);

        }).catch(err => {

          reject(err);

        })

      } else {

        resolve(result);

      }

    })

  }

  return rec(arr);

}

function succesHandler(data, index) {

  // Here i can alter 'data'
  data['finishedPromiseNr'] = index;

  console.log("promise test ", data, index);

  console.log("Go for next ");

  return data;

}

function errorHandler(err) {
  console.log("Error occurred ", err);
}

function submitAjaxData(form, datafield) {
  console.log("called submitAjaxData  ", datafield);
  //var loadurl = domainName + "/ajax-call-handler";

  // Mock some requests with delayed responses
  // https://reqres.in/#console
  var loadurl = "https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=" + datafield.fakeDelay;
  return $.ajax({
    url: loadurl,
    method: "GET",
    data: datafield
  });
}

function formPostSubmission(form) {
  var parts = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var i = 0;
  let poll = [];
  parts.forEach(function(entry) {
    i++;

    // 'datafield' was not assigned with var or let
    // Reassigning it on each loop will allow 'datafield' to pass in the anonymous function below
    let datafield = {
      answer: entry,
      displayOrder: i,
      ajaxName: 'statementPartialSubmit',
      fakeDelay: parts.length - i
    };

    // Wrong: submitAjaxData is called, that means, the requests are sent immediately.
    // poll.push( $.when(submitAjaxData(form, datafield) );

    // Correct: Wrap and return $.when into a function otherwise 'submitAjaxData' will trigger the requests
    poll.push(() => $.when(submitAjaxData(form, datafield)));

  });

  PromiseAllSeq(poll, succesHandler).then(responseList => {

    console.log('final response');
    console.log(responseList);

  }).catch(errorHandler)


}

formPostSubmission(null);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async: false
```

is the best option in your case

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `async: false`  was deprecated years ago because of negative user experience.